# HTTP POST Objective C

Tags: objective-c, web-services, curl

I am trying to do a post via http with no succes here is my code

```
NSError *error;
NSHTTPURLResponse *response;

NSData *posting =
[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:[input createJsonDictionary]
                                options:0
                                  error:&error];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", kURL]];
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[urlRequest setValue:@"application/json"
  forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[urlRequest setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"AuthToken %@",token]
  forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
[urlRequest setHTTPBody:posting];

NSData *urlResponse =
[NSData dataWithData:[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                           returningResponse:&response error:&error]];
NSDictionary *jsonDictionary =
[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urlResponse
                                options:0
                                  error:&error];

NSLog(@"status code: %i", [response statusCode]);

NSLog(@"URL: %@", [urlRequest URL]);
NSLog(@"header: %@ \n method: %@", [urlRequest allHTTPHeaderFields], [urlRequest HTTPMethod]);
NSLog(@"body: %@\n", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[urlRequest HTTPBody] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

In the NSLog I am getting back status code 500, there is a error. But when i try to do the same command using cURL

```
curl --request POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" 
-H "Authorization: AuthToken TOKEN" --data '{"DATA"}' -sL 
-w "\\n%{http_code} %{url_effective}\\n" https://URL.com
```

I get back status code 201, succes. Something seems to be off in my code. Also in the NSLogs for urlRequest they equal whats in the curl command. Is there something I'm doing incorrectly?

Comment: Someone is probably gonna come up with an answer for this, but might I suggest using [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to capture and analyze both requests (from curl and your application) and look for differences between them, you might solve your problem using this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my own answer. The problem was that my code was making call to the server synchronously and the servers weren't set up to do synchronous web calls. Instead I had to use a instant variable of NSURLConnection and do the call asynchronously "sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:" and use the methods start/cancel with the instant variable.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", kURL]];
```

Try

```
NSString *urlText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", kURL];
urlText = [urlText stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlText];
```

Comment: sorry can't help much. I usually work with my own wrapper over ASIHTTPRequest for network comms I made public few days back.